# How do you generate random token

Tags: raku

I want to be able to generate a string that contains letters and numbers in Raku. I can't find a module that works.

I want to be able to generate something like this:
w6sj7d2j2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
say ("a".."z","A".."Z",0..9).flat.roll(8).join;   # M9lldSFC
```

`("a".."z","A".."Z",0..9)` specifies the list of characters that you want to occur in your random string.

`.flat` makes sure the ranges will be flattened to their elements

`.roll(8)` selects a random element from the list 8 times.

`.join` concatenates the selected elements from the list into a single string

Comment: I suppose technically a random **token** would be `token random($length = 8) { { ("a".."z","A".."Z",0..9).flat.roll($length).join } }` ;-)

Comment: Although tokens are effectively methods in a grammar, they do have a specific API, which I have to admit, I'm not very familiar with.  I think that at least it should be a named parameter, as the standard token appears to have a `:(*%_)` signature.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I've not had a problem passing positionals.  My `FuzzyToken` takes both positional and named, for instance.

Comment: I'm not sure Raku's tokens is what you are looking for. Those are, as @ElizabethMattijsen, methods in a grammar, or basically regular expressions with certain characteristics (ratcheting, IARC). So you would be generating something like a regular expression that would match a random string, and a different one at that, every time...

Comment: jjmerelo: there's a reason I put an emoticon at the end jaja  I was just making a joke about the person asking about a random *token* — it would be fairly useless, as you say, because it has a virtual 0 chance of ever matching.